# Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent using vertcat

Tags: matlab

I get this error messge everytime I run my code. I have searched through other questions that are the same and tried the solutions but they have not worked. The error message is below followed by the code.

Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in project2 (line 147)
e = [a0;c0;d0];

```
N = length(z1);
if length(w)~=N, error('z and sw must be same length');
end
M = N-1;
a0 = zeros(2*M-2,(3*M));
b0 = zeros(2*M-2,1);
for i = 1:M-1
    co = i;
    ro = 2*(i-1)+1;
    a0(ro,co) = w(i+1)^2;
    a0(ro+1,co+1) = w(i+1)^2;
    a0(ro,co+n) = w(i+1);
    a0(ro+1,co+n+1) = w(i+1);
    a0(ro,co+2*n) = 1;
    a0(ro+1,co+2*n+1) = 1;
    b0(ro) = z1(i+1);
    b0(ro+1) = z1(i+1);
end
c0 = zeros(M-1,(3*M));
for i = 1:M-1
    c0(i,i) = 2*w(i+1);
    c0(i,i+1) = -2*w(i+1);
    c0(i,i+n) = 1;
    c0(i,i+n+1) = -1;
end
d0 = zeros(2,(3*M));
d0(1,1) = w(1)^2;
d0(1,M+1) = w(1);
d0(1,2*M+1) = 1;
d0(2,M) = w(end)^2;
d0(2,2*M) = w(end);
d0(2,end) = 1;
e = [a0;c0;d0];
```

Comment: Well...what are the dimensions of `a0, c0, d0`? Your code isn't functional.

Comment: a0, c0, and d0 start as matrices of zeros with dimensions (2*M-2,(3*M)), (M-1,(3*M)), and (2,(3*M)) respectively. They are then populated with data from w and z1. I don't understand why I can't use vertcat when the number of columns is the same for each.

Comment: They're apparently not the same. Put a breakpoint at the last line and check the dimensions of your matrices.

Comment: Because they're very likely not the same anymore. Use [the debugger](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) to see their dimensions at the line which causes the error. If you provided a [mcve] we could also do the same...

Comment: a0 is 14 columns wide while c0 and d0 are 12. I changed that and now my code works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent in 1x6802 double and 6802x1 double data matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830099/dimensions-of-matrices-being-concatenated-are-not-consistent-in-1x6802-double-an)