# Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent in 1x6802 double and 6802x1 double data matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to export m file signal to matfile in simulink. Here I am having a problem. My code is

```
Y;
X;
T;
K=zeros(1,6802);
for n=1:10:6800;
    angle=atan((Y(n+10)-Y(n))/(X(n+10)-X(n)));
    K(n)=angle;
end
yt=[T;K],
plot(T,K)
```

The error message is 
**Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
Error in work1 (line 20415)
yt=[T;K],**

Here K=1x6802 double and T=6802x1 double. I have gone through similar problems and solution but exactly not found my answer. It would be very helpful if someone helps me in solving the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to vertically concatenate a row vector with a column vector. The number of columns for the two vectors do not match. That sounds like a problem, right?

Answer (score 1):

Given the dimensions of `K` and `T`, you will have to transpose (the `'` operator) one in order to combine into a new matrix:

```
yt=[T';K]; % dimensions will be 2x6802
```